# What is the code to print text into a new line on assembly code, on HCS12 microcontroller using CodeWarrior?

Tags: assembly, codewarrior, 68hc12

I need my output to be put in colons on the terminal but they always display in the first row. I need to implement a part of code (which I am trying to find out on YouTube but they are using different microprocessors and I am not very familiar with assembly language to make the difference) to make instead of a space an enter to jump to the next row.

For example, how can I print the output of this loop in a new line every time this loop runs:

```
Label2:
 JSR out2hex                ; print the counter
 LDAB #$3A                  ; load to B ASCII code of ":"
 JSR putchar                ;print to the screen the character
 LDAB #$24                  ; load to B the character of ASCII code of "$"
 JSR putchar                ; print to the screen the character
 LDAB A,X                   ; load to B the value of X+A
 JSR out2hex                ; print into the screen the hex value of it
 INCA                       ; increment the counter, the value in   
                            ;accumulator A
 LDAB #$82                  ; load to B the ASCII code of ","
 JSR putchar                ; print the character of it
 CMPA #20                   ; compare the counter with 20 (which represents  
                            ;the number of elements in the array
 BNE Loop2                  ; branch if the counter in A is not equal to 20     
                            ;to the Loop2
```

Comment: What terminal?  Perhaps you need carriage return *and* newline?

Comment: @Peter Cordes. Yes there has to be with carriage return but I do not know the code which does it. The terminal is on the CodeWarrior software.

Comment: newline `'\n'` is ASCII code 10 (0xa).

Comment: @Peter Codes. I edited the question with a current code that I have, every time this code runs it displays the output in a row. Can you play modify it so it can show the output in different rows every time it runs? I am just trying to get the idea of how to list different outputs on the lines that the program needs.

Comment: Have you even tried outputting an ASCII newline carriage return with `putchar`?  Your current code doesn't output either, so it's not surprising the cursor stays on the same line.

Comment: $82 is not ASCII (0-127), and it's certainly not comma (as comments say).  `Label2` is same as `Loop2`? Replace $82 (that you call comma) with ASCII 13 followed by ASCII 10 to have a CR/LF sequence printed.  Learn the most common ASCII codes by heart, not that difficult.  This is useful for any language, not just assembly.